# Dynamic Compilation, ReferencedAssemblies.Add another Project

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, reference, class-library, codedom

will appreciate any pointers here.

- I am creating a Solution that have multiple Projects.
- The solution  have various class libraries that I create (libCore, libApplication, libUser).
- One project in the Solution is webApplication-A that will dynamically compile some VB.Net codes (input from user).

**Problem**: I cannot figure out how to add the assembly of one of my library to be used by the dynamic code, in this case libUser.dll.

- I have already added libUser as a reference to the webApplication-A project (which is compiling the code).
- I can see that libUser.dll is in the project's Bin directory.

---

```
Dim voCompiler As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
Dim voCompilerParams As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters

voCompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll")
voCompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("libUser.dll") '<<=== Cannot load this assembly
```

Comment: Beware that you are probably creating a giant security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the full path to the assembly:

```
voCompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(GetType(SomeType).Assembly.Location)
```

Comment: Ahh... the full path. How dumb of me :)
In this case:
     voCompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( Server.Mappath("Bin\libUser.dll"))

Comment: @JosephLee: My way is better; it means you don't need to update that if you rename the assembly.